# DataTables for large CSV files

Tags: php, csv, datatables

I'm using datatables to display data from a CSV file. The file may have 60k rows. All works well apart from it obviously takes a long time (over 70 seconds) to display.

```
<?php 
$result  = [];
if (($handle = fopen("SO.csv?id=2", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $cols = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);
        $reset = false;
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row[0].' </td><td> '.$row[1].' </td><td>  '.$row[2].' </td><td>  '.$row[3].' </td></tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

Obviously server-side would be an ideal option but I'm not sure how I'd incorporate it whilst reading from a CSV.

Any suggestions? Any other tools/scripts?

Comment: Simply save your echo output to html file.. and then open it directly

Comment: Did that but even with 60k rows, it's slow

Comment: This is good for one page view... if you want to show everything you need to use more advanced mechanism... For example you can Split the data to pages... send the first page and then send the rest asyncronously using ajax from the client side.... Or just use a framework with sql database like wordpress...

Comment: I can only use a CSV file - No MySQL and creating HTML files surely won't work if you need to filter

Comment: filter? plz explain...

Comment: The search option within datatables

Answer (score 1):

Try writing a PHP script that returns the CSV data, and then loading such data via the [ajax option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) in datatables. Then you can paginate the table and use the [deferRender](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender) option, which forces Datatables to create the HTML nodes only when needed (i.e. when changing pages).

This should speed up the initial loading quite a bit.

Comment: Besides converting CSV file into a database and using server-side processing mode, using `deferRender` with `ajax` or `data` options is the best alternative.